# How do I put values into these arrays with loop and Scanner?

Tags: java, arrays

Questions from my assignment:

a. Define a integer array, character array, float array. Use an array size of 10.

b. Put values into the above array using a loop statement and using Scanner

So far i have,

```
public class ArrayDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Define integer array, character array, float array
    int[] a = new int[10];
    char[] b = new char[10];
    float[] c = new float[10]; 

    // Input values using loop and Scanner
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter " + a.length + " values: ");
    for(int index1 = 0; index1 < a.length; index1++)
        a[index1] = input.nextInt()
    System.out.println("Enter " + b.length + " values for char: ");
    for(char index1 = 0; index1 < b.length; index1++)
        b[index1] = input.next(".").charAt(0);
    System.out.println("Enter " + c.length + " values for float: ");
    for(float index1 = 0; index1 < c.length; index1++) 
        c[index1] = input.nextFloat();
```

However, the last line has an error saying: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from float to int

Comment: so what exactly is the problem?

Comment: how do i input values for the char array and the float array as well

Comment: Probably `input.nextFloat()` for the float array, and `input.next(".")` for the char array?

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` has a `nextFloat()` for getting `float`s fashion to `nextInt()`. Just call it in its own loop:

```
System.out.print("Enter " + c.length + " float values: ");
for(int index1 = 0; index1 < c.length; index1++) {
    c[index1] = input.nextFloat();
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no `nextChar()` method, so you'd have to emulate it with `next(String)`'s variant that accepts a pattern:

```
System.out.print("Enter " + b.length + " char values: ");
for(int index1 = 0; index1 < b.length; index1++) {
    b[index1] = input.next(".").charAt(0);
}
```

Comment: @RuthWu I don't understand that comment. Can you elaborate?

Comment: for b[index1] = input.nextFloat(); says there's an error: possible lossy conversion from float to int?

Comment: @Mureinik `b` is `char[]`. not `float[]`. Also `next(".")` will return `String`, not `char` (you may want to add `charAt(0)` here), and it will work only if there is delimiter right after character (or end of data).

Comment: Got my `b` and `c` mixed up :-(